# UI related shiny inputs R

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I have this code from the shiny UI.

I want one input to depend in other input in the UI. So lets say if the user insert 100 in one input I want the MIN of the other input to be input$1 * 5 for example. So in that case the min of the input number 2 would be 500.

Ill attach the code I wanted to work but it doesn't.Is there any other workaround you can think of?

Thanks

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  (titlePanel("Price estimation", windowTitle = "app")),

  sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel(

    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkgroupuno",
                       label = "Select stages",
                       choices = c("Proekt","Working Design",
                                   "Tender Design", "Concept"),
                       selected = "Proekt", inline = F),

    radioButtons(inputId = "radiouno",
                       label = "Select Design",
                       choices = c("Shell & Core","Fit Out",
                                   "Shell Core & Fit Out"),
                       selected = "Shell & Core", inline = F),

    sliderInput(inputId = "slideruno",
                label = "Size", min = 0, max = 250000, value = 50000,ticks = T),

    sliderInput(inputId = "sliderdos",
                label = "TIME", min = input$slideruno * 10, max = input$slideruno * 15, value = input$slideruno * 10,ticks = T)



  ),

  mainPanel(plotlyOutput(outputId = "plotuno"))
  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create your slider, as so:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Price estimation", windowTitle = "app"),

  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkgroupuno",label = "Select stages",
                       choices = c("Proekt","Working Design","Tender Design", "Concept"),selected = "Proekt", inline = F),

    radioButtons(inputId = "radiouno",label = "Select Design",choices = c("Shell & Core","Fit Out","Shell Core & Fit Out"),selected = "Shell & Core", inline = F),
    sliderInput(inputId = "slideruno",label = "Size", min = 0, max = 250000, value = 50000,ticks = T),
    uiOutput("custom_sliderdos")    
  )

  ,mainPanel(plotlyOutput(outputId = "plotuno"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$custom_sliderdos <- renderUI({sliderInput(inputId = "sliderdos", label = "TIME", min = input$slideruno * 10, max = input$slideruno * 15, value = input$slideruno * 10,ticks = T)})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]